# Что нужно добавить в user-agent, чтобы знать что запрос на сайт приходит из приложения?

Tags: android

В мобильном приложении используется webview. Что нужно добавить в user-agent, чтобы на сайте различать, используется ли приложение или просто мобильный браузер?

Метод webView.getSettings().getUserAgentString() выводит:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; Redmi 3S Build/MMB29M; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/64.0.3282.137 Mobile Safari/537.36
```

Comment: Нужно добавить в iser-agent что-нибудь.

Comment: Руслан Ягупов, это не дубль, в первом случае спрашивалось как узнать user-agent и можно ли его изменить, а во втором случае что нужно в него добавить, чтобы понять, что запрос идет из приложения

Comment: Ok, просто добавьте в него Android/%Версия приложения% и пусть проверяют на сервере